# Store data in Firebase for a limited time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store something in database for a limited time. After which it will be removed.

For example:

```
UNIQUE_USER_KEY: {
      EXAMPLE_KEY: some_value
      TIME: 60    (in minutes)
}
```

In the example above `some_value` should be changed to `null` after 1 hour (60 minutes). I want it to happen regardless of the life cycle status of the app i.e. even if the user deleted the application all together.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to store time? I have **no idea** how to do this and would rally appreciate insight on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet (currently) is to set up a recurring job to periodically sweep entries out of your database.  You can do this with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and a scheduling mechanism you provide.  There is a [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA) about this.

I suggesting storing the time to delete as an abosolute date in time (like `System.currenTimeMillis()`) rather than as a delay so you can query the database for everything that ought to be deleted at this moment.

Comment: Is there no easier way to do it? Because I would have multiple nodes with, each with their own time. Therefore, they would have to be updated independently.

Comment: There is currently no scheduling mechanism built into Firebase.  This is the best you can do for now.